# Error: unable to find CUDA device 0 among 2 EGL devices in total when testing Habitat-Lab on WSL 2

Tags: windows, github, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, wsl-2

I am trying to install habitat-lab for research from this [Github Repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-lab#installation).
I have completed all the install steps in the **installation** section, but when it comes to the **testing** part, when I run the command

```
python examples/interactive_play.py --never-end
```

I am getting following errors:

```
pybullet build time: May 20 2022 19:45:31
2023-11-21 00:41:00,656 Initializing dataset RearrangeDataset-v0
2023-11-21 00:41:09,612 initializing sim RearrangeSim-v0
[00:41:09:624548]:[Warning]:[Metadata] AttributesManagerBase.h(398)::buildAttrSrcPathsFromJSONAndLoad : <Articulated Object> : No Glob path result found for `data/hab_fetch_1.0/robots/fetch_no_base.urdf` so unable to load templates from that path.
[00:41:09:646583]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_00.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646618]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_01.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646628]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_02.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646634]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_03.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646641]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_04.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646647]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_05.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646653]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_06.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646659]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_07.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646665]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_08.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646671]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_09.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646677]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_10.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646683]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_11.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646689]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_12.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646710]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_13.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646731]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_14.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646752]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_15.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646760]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_16.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646766]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_17.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646772]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_18.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646778]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_19.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
[00:41:09:646784]:[Warning]:[Metadata] SceneDatasetAttributesManager.cpp(124)::loadAndValidateMap : `navmesh_instances` Value : `navmeshes/v3_sc4_staging_20.navmesh` not found on disk as absolute path or relative to `data/replica_cad`
Platform::WindowlessEglApplication::tryCreateContext(): unable to find CUDA device 0 among 2 EGL devices in total
WindowlessContext: Unable to create windowless context
```

I have checked and ensured that the CUDA Toolkit has been installed, but I still encounter this error. Is there any way to fix this issue, or is it simply not possible to install habitat-lab on WSL 2?